# Authentication via rest with symfony2

Tags: web-services, rest, symfony

I'm new with symfony2 and i am trying to connect with FOSUserBundle via a rest api.
The web browser authentication is working fine and I can create users with FOSUserBundle.
In fact I want to build a webservice with Symfony.
How can I connect a user vie rest ?
Is it a bundle to use rest with symfony2 easily?

Thanks.

Comment: You should have a look at [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using "Wsse" as authorization method.

You can read about that at [this post](http://obtao.com/blog/2013/06/configure-wsse-on-symfony2-use-it-with-fosrestbundle-and-test-it-with-chrome/).
There is even [a bundle](https://github.com/escapestudios/EscapeWSSEAuthenticationBundle) that provide wsse routines.

About make REST-ful your app, i would suggest using [FosRestBundle](https://github.com/sdiaz/FOSRestBundleByExample)

Answer (score 0):

For authenticating the user, first you create an action that will take the user name and password. Then find the user from database according to the username and password. For making pass as in database you have to make the password as FOSUserBundle is making it. Later u need to create UsernamePasswordToken. For that u can use the following code in action

```
$providerKey = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

I think it will help you.

Comment: this is wrong answer. REST API must have custom authentication provider in order not to use cookies to maintain the logged in user.

this is a fine article on how to do that.
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html